# How to write a recursive function template in C++ that checks whether two stacks provided as parameters are identical?

Tags: c++

I have to complete a function template for a module I'm doing and the question reads as follow:
Write a recursive function template, identicalS that checks whether two stacks provided as
parameters are identical. If that is the case, the function should return the Boolean value true
otherwise the Boolean value false should be returned.
Use the following header:
*template 

bool identicalS (stackType S1, stackType S2);*

Below is my code which I have not tested but I'm asking you if it would work and if not how will you correct it:

```
template <class Type>
bool identicalS (stackType<Type> S1, stackType<Type> S2);


template <class Type>
bool identicalS (stackType<Type> S1, stackType<Type> S2)
{
    Type lh, rh;
    int ret = 0;

    if ( (lh = s1.pop()) == (rh = s2.pop()) ) {
        if ( !s1.isEmptyStack() and !s2.isEmptyStack() ) return identicalS(s1, s2);
        else ret = 1;
    }
    s1.push(lh);
    s2.push(rh);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ steer towards providing arguments as const references, as in `const stackType<Type>& S1`.

Comment: Where did you define `stackType`? Are you also aware that a template must be fully defined before it's used? There are at least two fundamental reasons why the shown code is broken. `stackType` is not defined anywhere. The `identicals` template is defined only after it used. Sorry, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "a template must be fully defined before it's used" Is that correct? In this instance, the function template prototype and definition are in the same translation unit. Why would that be an issue?

Comment: I'm a newbie with C++. I thought stackType was a predefined data type. I understand now my code will never work unless I define stackType as a stack type. @SamVarshavchik, will the function  identicalS  work according to the specifications of the question if everything else is ignored? If stackType is defined.